# Getting latest directory from another server

Tags: shell, unix

Test1 Server :-   ut1-2013.02.**26**-04.42.15 , ut1-2013.02.**25**-09.21.11 ,  ut1-2013.02.**21**-09.22.32   (Dir's)
Test2 Server :- ut1-2013.02.**25**-09.21.11 ,  ut1-2013.02.**21**-09.22.32

There are two servers :- Test1 and Test2
Having Directories :- As shown above

Latest Directory in test1 server :- ut1-2013.02.**26**-04.42.15
Latest Directory in test2 server :- ut1-2013.02.**25**-09.21.11

When I am running the below command from **test2 server's** command line

command :- ssh test1 ls -ldt ut1-????.??.??-??.??.?? | head -1

I am getting the output as ut1-2013.02.**25**-09.21.11(latest dir in test2 server),
but the output which I am expecting in ut1-2013.02.**26**-04.42.15 (latest directory in test1 server) ?

Please help me getting the latest directory  ut1-2013.02.**26**-04.42.15 from test2 server using ssh ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encase the file spec with quotes - otherwise the spec will be interpreted by the local shell.

```
ssh test1 ls -ldt "ut1-????.??.??-??.??.??" | head -1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, target achieved